# DataFormatString not working with data grid

Tags: vb.net, export-to-excel

I have a format issue with data grid. I have applied the formatting property `aDataColumn.DataFormatString = "{0:d}"`

```
Private Function CreateColumnFromNode(ByVal aDisplayPropertyNode As XmlNode) As BoundColumn
        Dim PropertyKey As String = cXMLDoc.AttributeToString(aDisplayPropertyNode, "PropertyKey")
        Dim ColumnHeader As String = ConfigurableText(cXMLDoc.AttributeToString(aDisplayPropertyNode, "ColumnHeader"))
        If PropertyKey = "" Then Return Nothing
        Dim aDataColumn As New BoundColumn()
        aDataColumn.DataField = PropertyKey
            aDataColumn.HeaderText = IIf(ColumnHeader = "", PropertyKey, ColumnHeader)
                       <b> aDataColumn.DataFormatString = "{0:d}"</b>
                    Return aDataColumn
    End Function
```

to data grid. While exporting to excel it takes the default settings of the system.

I have used the following code for exporting. Not a custom code.

It uses asp.net proprty.

```
       Dim response As HttpResponse = HttpContext.Current.Response
    response.Clear()
    response.Charset = ""
    ' set the response mime type 
    response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
    response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + aFileName)
    ' create a string writer

    Using sw As System.IO.StringWriter = New System.IO.StringWriter()
        Using htw As HtmlTextWriter = New HtmlTextWriter(sw)
            ' instantiate a datagrid

            DataGrid1.RenderControl(htw)
            response.Write(sw.ToString())
        End Using
    End Using
    response.End()
```

Thanks..

Comment: This question is a little hard to understand, what is the expected result and what is currently happening?

Comment: Also you seem to be trying to highlight one of your code lines with bold tags, which won't work here for two reasons: the input form doesn't accept HTML for formatting, and you can't format inside a code block.

Comment: Hi Adrian,  have used bouncolumn not bounField. So I can't give HTMLEncode="False".  Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest that the reason you're getting the default system settings when exporting to Excel is because of Excel's automatic cell formatting feature, which will look at a cell 's value contents and automatically apply one of its pre-defined formats to it unless a specific format is otherwise specified by the user to override this one.

As we can't see your Excel export code I'll assume you're doing that yourself, in which case you need to add a line to the code to either set the datetime format of that column or else set its format to text.  To test this open one of the spreadsheets you've exported already and change the format of the column to text and see if it gives you your original data back.